# failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli)

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I need to make for school a Maven project.

It's a project to use JPA. I added all the needed dependencies. And when I run the project I get the following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project se42Her: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

I checked a lot of questions asked before but they didn't work. I added my POM below.  Thanks in advance. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>nl.se42HER</groupId>
<artifactId>se42Her</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>se42Her</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClass>nl.se42her.se42her.MainApp</mainClass>
</properties>

<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>Your Organisation</name>
</organization>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                        <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-createjar</argument>
                            <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                            <argument>-appclass</argument>
                            <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                            <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                            <argument>-outdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                            <argument>-outfile</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The  errors I get:

Error 1:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for
>   Manifest main attributes  at
>   sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:284)
>     at
>   sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
>     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:273)     at
>   java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)    at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)    at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)    at
>   sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(JarIndex.java:137)  at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:839)  at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:831)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:830)     at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.(URLClassPath.java:803)     at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:530)    at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:520)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:519)    at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:492)    at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(URLClassPath.java:457)    at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:211)  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
>   Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main"

Error 2:

> INFO [org.netbeans.spi.lexer.MutableTextInput]: !!WARNING!! Missing 
>   READ-LOCK when accessing TokenHierarchy:
>   input-source:org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@1ae8c632,
>   mimeType='text/x-maven-pom+xml', kitClass=null, length=5342,
>   version=13,
>   file=org.netbeans.modules.maven.grammar.POMDataObject@467490[C:\Users\Tjidde
>   Nieuwenhuizen\Documents\GitHub\SE42Her\se42Her\pom.xml@4283ecb8:2052c29a]
>   java.lang.Exception   at
>   org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenHierarchyOperation.ensureReadLocked(TokenHierarchyOperation.java:406)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenHierarchyOperation.tokenSequence(TokenHierarchyOperation.java:431)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenHierarchyOperation.tokenSequence(TokenHierarchyOperation.java:427)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.api.lexer.TokenHierarchy.tokenSequence(TokenHierarchy.java:186)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.xml.text.completion.XMLCompletionQuery.shouldCloseTag(XMLCompletionQuery.java:468)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.xml.text.completion.XMLCompletionQuery.queryValues(XMLCompletionQuery.java:351)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.xml.text.completion.XMLCompletionQuery.query(XMLCompletionQuery.java:127)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.xml.text.completion.XMLCompletionProvider$Query.query(XMLCompletionProvider.java:124)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.spi.editor.completion.support.AsyncCompletionTask.run(AsyncCompletionTask.java:223)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
>     at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)    at
>   org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)

I'm trying to run the following code. 
https://github.com/tjidde-nl/SE42Her/blob/master/se42Her/src/main/java/nl/se42her/se42her/FXMLController.java which uses 
https://github.com/tjidde-nl/SE42Her/blob/master/se42Her/src/main/java/DOA/CustomerDAOImpl.java

Comment: add the full stack trace

Comment: and post WHAT you are running, the code!

Comment: Did you define `mvn ... -D runfx.args=...` on the command line?

Comment: Added the errors to post